# PowerShell get or stop a particular Java process

Tags: java, powershell, jar

I am using PowerShell script to start multiple Java application.

```
$app = Start-Process -FilePath java -ArgumentList "-jar $path_to_jar" -PassThru
```

it's working as expected.

But I also have to search a particular Java process and stope/close it.
*I cant use process id ($app.ID) as stop script will be a different script.*

**Can I have some custom name/identifier to these Java process to get a particular process ? like if I can fetch a java process by JAR name etc.**

Not sure but in Linux environment I have seen use of `-DAPP_INSTANCE_NAME` flag , that might be a custom flag to identify a process.

Any help is apricated.

Comment: Why not store the PID and any descriptive information in a log file that can be parsed by your stop script?

Comment: @thepip3r - that's one option. probably the last option if nothing comes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am using [JPS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) , it's command

```
& jps -v
```

returning all the details like jar name etc. and that result I am using for filtering out the process id.

Answer (score 0):

leave a snippet here

```
Get-Process -Id ((jps) | Select-String -Pattern '([0-9]+)\s+foo\.jar').Matches.Groups[1].Value | Stop-Process
```

if you not sure if this process exist

```
(jps).where({$_ -match '^([0-9]+)\s+foo\.jar'})
# add check here
Get-Process -Id $Matches.1 | Stop-Process
```

Note for Windows user : On my computer , `Get-WmiObject -Query ...`([wmic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643901) in powershell) sometimes return empty `CommandLine` property. And this jps way works fine.